# IPC via mmap'ed file: should atomics and/or volatile be used?

Tags: c++, ipc, atomic, volatile, mmap

I use a mmap'ed file to share data between processes.

The code is like this:

```
struct Shared
{
int Data;
};

int file = open("file.dat", O_RDWR);
Shared* shared = static_cast<Shared*>(
    mmap(0, sizeof(Shared), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_POPULATE, file, 0));
shared->Data++;
```

The questions are:

1. Should I use volatile qualifier (`volatile int Data`)?
2. Should I use atomic operations on the shared data (`__sync_fetch_and_add(&(shared->Data), 1)`)?

---

For future reference: [Volatile: Almost Useless for Multi-Threaded Programming](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2007/11/30/volatile-almost-useless-for-multi-threaded-programming/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use volatile when changing an integer from more than one thread. Volatile is both not necessary and not sufficient. Atomic operations will do.

Comment: Threads have nothing to do with processes (IPC stands for inter-process communication).

Comment: @VJo: Huh? A process is at least one thread. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Yes, it is at least one thread, but what atomic operations have to to with processes? In a case of mmap-ed data, you do not need anything special to access it.

Comment: @VJo: Dude, did you read the question? The data is shared between processes.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that `volatile` will work correctly across multiple processors, the thing you need to check is whether that intrinsic inserts the appropriate memory barriers during the operation.

Is this some sort of semaphore? if so, you are better off using the platform implementation of such a construct.

Comment: It's not a semaphore, it's a shared counter. That is, a meaningful piece of data that could be altered by several processes.

Answer (score -1):

No need for both volatile and atomic accesses. IPC using mmap works fine without them.

If you need to inform whether something changed, you can use [message queues](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mq_open), but you can also use them instead of mmap (depends how big is the message you want to send. mmap works good is the data is big, but MQ is it is smaller then 200k)

Comment: The primary reason to use mmap here is for persistense. I want the data to be retained on disk between runs, and this way I don't have to implement any kind serialization (and also can be sure to have the actual data saved if the process terminates unexpectedly).

Comment: @VladV In that case, shared memory is the way to go. Not mmap

Comment: dude, you don't seem to have any idea about the things you are talking about. You can not use shared memory without using mmap(). In fact, all virtual memory of a process is mapped using mmap().

Comment: @Maxim Off course I know, but it looks like you don't. JFYI : http://fscked.org/writings/SHM/shm-1.html#ss1.1 I am sure you can find good examples online.

Comment: the link you posted has no relevance. I suggest you remove all your comments in this thread to avoid further embarrassment.